# Verilog wire is not assigned

Tags: verilog, variable-assignment

I was wondering that if a wire is declared in a Verilog code, but it is not assigned any value, does Verilog treat its value as ZERO ?

For example, I see a code where:

```
wire start;

module_if  my_module_if(.clk(in_clk), .start(start));
```

Can I assume that the value of "start" will be zero?
Is this an acceptable style for Verilog?

Answer (score 3):

Nets (including wire) without an assignment will be initialized to 'z' (aka high-impedance).

But if you are trying to use "start" as some kind variable or state, then you should probably declare it as "reg" or "logic" (System-Verilog) rather than "wire" (which tends to be used more for interconnect).

Style-wise, it may be less error-prone for you and for the reader of the code to be explicit about the initialization of your logic.  For example ...

```
logic start;
initial begin
  start = 1'b0;
end
```

Comment: Thanks. But I am reading someone else's code, whom I don't have access anymore. And, he is using exactly the way that I described, and he is kicking off a state machine based on "start". And, I looked carefully, and no other place "start" is given any value. And, that is why I thought it should be ZERO.

Comment: From the code you shared, all I can tell is that the parent module and 'my_module_if' are connected through the "start" net.  It is possible for the parent, 'my_module_if' or some other function/task or even some other module through hierarchical reference to drive 'start'.